# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "de rositas"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, españa

El Diccionario de la lengua, en [**rositas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WjJREOq), recoge:

> de rositas
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. De balde, sin esfuerzo alguno.

Por otro lado, [**FUNDEU**](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/irse-de-rositas-1086/) recoge que la locución "irse de rositas" figura, por ejemplo, en el *Diccionario fraseológico documentado del español actual*, de Seco, Andrés y Ramos, donde se da la siguiente definición:

> **de rositas.**
>   adv (col) Sin pagar lo que se debe o sin recibir el castigo merecido. Generalmente en la locución «irse de rositas».

Pero no he encontrado su origen.

Edición:

Las referencias más antiguas que he encontrado son:

> José Santa Coloma: *Fiestas reales de toros* (1878)
>
> > A los cinco terceros, Canales, el Chuchi, Melones y los de tanda, que no se descuidaron con el palo, como igualmente los reservas que ninguno se fué **de rositas**.

y en

> Pérez Galdós: *La Primera República* (1911):
>
> > Ponga usted también en su Historia que se llevó **de rositas** dos mil reales para sus gastos de viaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que puede ser una ironía.

*Irse de rosas* podría ser equivalente a "recibir rosas" (como *se fue de aplausos* significa que lo aplaudieron).

Como en este caso la persona en realidad lo que se merece es un castigo, se dice todo lo contrario, matizado con el diminutivo para que se entienda que se está siendo sarcástico.

Como recibir rosas es más o menos un símbolo de la premiación, *irse de rositas* significaría todo lo contrario, o sea "este señor no se merece ningún premio".

Answer (score 2):

Creo que Rodrigo va por buen camino. Nótese que no estoy seguro de si en tu primer ejemplo el uso de "irse de rositas" es literal o figurado. Véase este otro de 1876 que copio de la hemeroteca de la BNE;

> *Se presentó el cuarto, colorado, careto, capachito. Laborda dio varios lances de capa. Matacán picó dos veces, y Juanillo Bejarano una, yéndose ambos de rositas [...].*
>
> Boletín de loterías y de toros (Madrid). 20/11/1876, n.º 1.343, página 4.

En el mundo del toreo era (y supongo que sigue siendo) normal que cuando una persona cumplía dignamente su cometido se le tiraran rosas como premio, lo que hace de la expresión "irse de rositas" algo literal. Sin embargo, por la misma época se usaba la misma expresión para justo lo contrario: hacer algo sin esfuerzo alguno, en contraposición a los que tienen que esforzarse en cumplir su tarea.

> *Donde para la fiesta de los toro
>
>   no fartan a la gente veinte riale;
>
>   donde hay un sor que alumbra de rositas
>
>   á toos los que quieran disfrutarle.*
>
> El Globo (Madrid). 5/5/1879, n.º 1.298, página 3.

En este caso se indica que el sol alumbra sin ningún esfuerzo. En todo caso, esta expresión debió de tener su origen en Andalucía, a juzgar por el lenguaje usado en la rima anterior, que es el primer caso que encuentro de la expresión usada figuradamente. Esto me hace pensar si su origen no pudo haber sido otro, ya que encuentro noticias que hablan de una tal calle *de Rositas*, situada en el casco histórico de Sevilla, y de la que dicen así:

> *Gracias á la buena administración de la señá Agapita, tenia casa abierta en una de las calles más económicas de Sevilla; en la de Rositas.*
>
> El Periódico para todos. 31/1/1877, n.º 31, página 9.

Esto también podría haber influido en la creación de la expresión (en su versión "hacer algo de rositas"), dado que abrir un negocio en dicha calle sería algo que implicaría menos esfuerzo que en otros sitios. Hoy día esa calle se llama *[de Adolfo Cuéllar](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Calle+Adolfo+Cu%C3%A9llar,+41001+Sevilla)* y, aunque está un poco escondida, será de todo menos barata.